# Strapi + Hashicorp Vault Dynamic Database Secret

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi, hashicorp-vault

I have implemented a script and a cron task in strapi to generate new database secret from my vault server.

```
const client = new VaultEnv()
const secret = await client.secretManager()
strapi.config.set('database.connection.connection.user', secret.data.username)
strapi.config.set('database.connection.connection.password', secret.data.password)
```

So far the above code block only works at start-up in the `register({ strapi })` function at `src/index.js`, but after in cron task it updates the connection config but strapi seems to only use the config that was set at `register({ strapi })` function at start-up

I have also tried injecting into `process.env` but still the same result or I probably did it the wrong way.

[image]

Apparently it may be impossible but I will leave this question open in-case there are others searching.

A workaround will be to take advantage of container orchestration to restart strapi servers (agents) for zero downtime.